# Move data statement from multiples tables to another database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I move the data from all fields (*) and all tables from db1 to db2 with Oracle ?

Comment: Look at my answer here [Query two databases with Oracle SQL Developer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160272/8162877#8162877)

Answer (score 4):

You have two choices:

- use `exp` and `imp` (or, if using 10g or later, `expdp` and `impdp`);
- use a database link.

As you don't tell much about your environment etc, this is as close an answer as it gets...

Comment: I would like to know (see my title question) what is the sql statement to move the data? I know about exp/imp

Comment: If you have a database link, it is just a matter of `insert into tablename@linkname values ...;`. But using exp/imp (or expdp/impdp) will probably be faster (one advantage: they keep DDL intact)

Comment: And note that impdp can use database links too.

Comment: I do not know anything about my customers database version, the oracle "management studio" they use, therefore I need a sql statement they can run for migrating data from db1 to db2. There are no linknames or such stuff.

Comment: Well, you cannot reasonably expect to achieve that without a minimum effort from their part. Where is db1? Where is db2? What versions? You need to know all of these before you can even _begin_ to design a solution. There is no way around that. There is no magic SQL statement which can do that for you (and for them).

Comment: With MS SQL server it is that easy. Just a simple: INSERT INTO DB1.Tablename SELECT * FROM DB2.Tablename. This just confirms how developer unfriendly oracle is.

Comment: @Lisa Are you comparing schemas to databases?